# UWP unit test Error: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as XamlControlsResources

Tags: unit-testing, uwp

recently we updated our UWP project to use Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls to replace Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls for our NavigationViewItem, in order to avoid crashes on RS4. The crashes are due to some navigation view feature required RS5 or higher machine.

But after we update the UWP project, our unit test project (only the UWP one, .net ones are still working fine) stopped working. It's always skipped. And if I set the unit test project as startup project, I will hit an assert in UnhandledException callback set in InitializeComponent():

```
"Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'XamlControlsResources' was not found in namespace 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls'.
```

I am pretty sure this is caused by the UI library changes above (maybe namespace conflict?), but I cannot figure out how to fix it. I've updated VS 2017 to the latest release, also tried to update the unit test framework and NuGet packages, nothing helps.

The package we are using is:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml">
  <Version>2.1.190405004.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here, the real fix will probably in the next release from Microsoft.

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/230

I added the Nuget package to my unit test project, and also added a UnitTestAppMainPage.xaml. This made my UWP unit test project works again.